# JavaScript: <script> attribute src= fails to find scripts.js when it's in a subfolder

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, src

I'm an absolute beginner in JavaScript with an elementary problem I can't solve. I've searched this site but have found no question on point.

All the references say it is best practice to separate the JavaScript (and CSS) from the main HTML by putting it into a subfolder (ditto for the CSS). So I've created a folder (Rainbow-Project) and within it two subfolders (js and css) and put the JavaScript and CSS in them.

In the Rainbow-Project folder I've put the rainbow.html file, and in the js subfolder I've put the scripts.js file. There is no CSS for the exercise.

In rainbow.html there is the following:`<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>`. This throws a 404 file not found error which I see in the JavaScript console.

If instead I put the scripts.js file in the Rainbow-Project folder and change the `<script>` tag to read `<script src="scripts.js"></script>`, the rainbow.html  runs correctly and the JavaScript executes correctly.

I'm using a MacBook Air running OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 with Chrome 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit). But it's not browser specific; it's a cross browser problem that happens in Safari and Firefox as well. The folders were created with Finder.

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Your interest in my question and any help are much appreciated.

-Steve

Comment: Would you be able to provide what your directory structure looks like? If it's throwing a 404 the path is most likely just incorrect (slight typo or something maybe)

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively, without a doubt sure that `rainbow.html` is not in the same folder as `scripts.js`? Because if the latter method works then that tells me they're in the same folder.

Comment: Are you sure you put `js` and `css` folders **within** `Rainbow-Project` rather than at the **same** level as it?

Comment: Hmmm. All is well. When I tried to reproduce the 404 the program actually worked as expected. I swear I didn't change a thing.  "Sure" says you. But I think it's gremlins and I must have fed Gizmo or gotten him wet. Thanks for your interest and help, really. :-)